# Does link with rel="me" attribute provide any link juice advantage?

Tags: hyperlink, link-juice, rel-me

On my [Squidoo profile page](http://www.squidoo.com/lensmasters/athleticgear) I found my websites's link is in a `rel="me"` attribute.

Does this attribute provide any link juice advantage to my website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rel="me"` attribute for links is not give more PageRank (or link juice) to your linked webpage. It just means the link refers to *your* website attached to your profile.

Answer (score 3):

`rel="me"` links are treated the same as any other links, with the added functionality that they tell  Google that the two linking pages represent the same person.

Ideally they should be reciprocal links, so you should have one on your website linking back to your profile on http://www.squidoo.com/.

Something like this:

```
John Sanjay has also written <a rel="me" href="http://www.squidoo.com/lensmasters/athleticgear">lots of articles on his Squidoo Lense</a>.
```

[More info on `rel="me`" on can be found here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1229920)